# How do I interact with this iframe in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

```
textbox = driver.find_element_by_id('applicant.name')
```

doesn't work.

Unfortunately and I've tried every variation of inspect element, copy xpath , trying to identify the class name of the text boxes etc.

I want to be able to send some text to the input fields in the indeed-apply-widget seen [here](http://ca.indeed.com/cmp/Clearview-Plumbing-&-Heating/jobs/HVAC-Installer-Opening-6183dce44a9bfe10?sjdu=vQIlM60yK_PwYat7ToXhk42rccfWGklJDtD_zDpWBzDCfUEiSP2Zk-zLpFc6GNuF8wyV4_UaMyNFtpjETvX0fCpQXc3PxTbrGkwAMNkR5vGMtAfe9wNpTncItNgAIJHx).

If you click **'apply now'** (unfortunately I can't link it) you'll see the inputs are contained within 2 iframes.

Is there an easy way to access them?
Here's what I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://ca.indeed.com/cmp/Clearview-Plumbing-&-Heating/jobs/HVAC-Installer-Opening-6183dce44a9bfe10?sjdu=vQIlM60yK_PwYat7ToXhk42rccfWGklJDtD_zDpWBzDCfUEiSP2Zk-zLpFc6GNuF8wyV4_UaMyNFtpjETvX0fCpQXc3PxTbrGkwAMNkR5vGMtAfe9wNpTncItNgAIJHx' )
driver.find_element_by_class_name("indeed-apply-widget").click()
    # move into the iframe

iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
```

Updated Code (still unable to interact with the iframe)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://ca.indeed.com/cmp/Clearview-Plumbing-&-Heating/jobs/HVAC-Installer-Opening-6183dce44a9bfe10?sjdu=vQIlM60yK_PwYat7ToXhk42rccfWGklJDtD_zDpWBzDCfUEiSP2Zk-zLpFc6GNuF8wyV4_UaMyNFtpjETvX0fCpQXc3PxTbrGkwAMNkR5vGMtAfe9wNpTncItNgAIJHx' )
driver.find_element_by_class_name("indeed-apply-widget").click()
    # move into the iframe
path = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[2]/iframe")
driver.switch_to_frame(path)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="applicant.name"]').sendKeys("TEST_NAME")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element that you want is inside two nested `IFRAME`s. The below code should work. You need to go into the first frame... and then the first nested frame. The rest should work at that point.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://ca.indeed.com/cmp/Clearview-Plumbing-&-Heating/jobs/HVAC-Installer-Opening-6183dce44a9bfe10?sjdu=vQIlM60yK_PwYat7ToXhk42rccfWGklJDtD_zDpWBzDCfUEiSP2Zk-zLpFc6GNuF8wyV4_UaMyNFtpjETvX0fCpQXc3PxTbrGkwAMNkR5vGMtAfe9wNpTncItNgAIJHx')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.indeed-apply-button-label")).click()
driver.switch_to_frame(0)
driver.switch_to_frame(0)
driver.find_element_by_id("applicant.name")).send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id("applicant.email")).send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_id("resume")).send_keys(resumePath)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.button_content.form-page-next")).click()
driver.find_element_by_id("apply")).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the observation JeffC. I still can't click the button though for some reason ...I'm trying to click the last apply button <input class="button_content" id="apply" name="apply" value="Apply" type="submit">

Comment: Are you signed in or something? I don't see the element you are referring to in the DOM on my page. The Apply Now button looks like this on my page: `<span class="indeed-apply-button-label" id="indeed-ia-1444972086694-1label">Apply Now</span>`

Comment: JeffC ohh if you click that theres a form that comes up. I have it mostly filled out but then theres another apply button that just says "Apply" I want to click that. I already clicked the "Apply Now" button to launch the form.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your feedback. I was looking at the wrong button.

Comment: <div class="form_actions"><div class="button_outter"><div class="button_inner"><input class="button_content" id="apply" name="apply" value="Apply" type="submit">

Comment: how do I select this answer as the best answer? nvm figured it out!

Comment: No problem... glad to help and glad it worked for you.